# Files deleted from within /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/

Tags: docker, filesystems

The [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/) state:

> Warning: Do not directly manipulate any files or directories within `/var/lib/docker/`. These files and directories are managed by Docker.

Let's say someone hasn't read that hint and deleted some files from `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` to free up some disk space. These files didn't live in a *Docker volume* and are not part of the original *Docker image* but have been created in the *container writable layer*. Restarting the given container frees up the disk space but are there any known side effects?

And for the next time: Does removing that kind of files or directories from within the container (via docker exec .. rm ..) result in a proper removal or are they only marked as deleted? The documentation currently doesn't describe this special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Restarting the given container frees up the disk space but are there any known side effects?

As you stated in your question, you should not *"manipulate any files or directories within /var/lib/docker/"*, as any side-effect may appear and no documentation trace anything about this: it's internal Docker plumbing which may highly change other Docker versions, ut's not supposed to be exposed to end-users nor be tempered with. You could look at Docker code for your Docker version and all it's dependencies to understand what happened, but it's not really practical :-)

> are there any known side effects?

**There maybe be** side effects - I insist on the *may* as anything can happen depending on your Docker version and configuration. Even if it may seem to be working, some things may be broken.

Well known side effect is Docker installation corruption, which may have present itself in various fashions: random container crash, data loss, unexplained bug, etc.

- Best case scenario, you just discarded some data in your container and everything will work fine in the future.
- Not-so-good scenario: you actually broke something in your installation and corrupted it, you'll be better of re-installing Docker entirely.

> Does removing that kind of files or directories from within the container (via docker exec .. rm ..) result in a proper removal or are they only marked as deleted?

Deleting a file in the container will not always remove it from the system, it depends on the drive your are using. Doc has a section about writing files for all of them:

- [AUFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/#modifying-files-or-directories) - it seemed implied that file is deleted, AUFS will copy the file from the image layer and work on it, it should then delete the copy

  > When a file is deleted within a container, a whiteout file is created in the container layer. The version of the file in the image layer is not deleted [...] Subsequent writes to the same file operate against the copy of the file already copied up to the container.
- [BTRFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/#writing-files) - deleted and space reclaimed, doc is quite clear:

  > If a container creates a file and then deletes it, this operation is performed in the Btrfs filesystem itself and the space is reclaimed.
- [devicemapper](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#writing-files) - may not be deleted depending on config:

  > if you are using `direct-lvm`, the blocks are freed. If you use `loop-lvm`, the blocks may not be freed
- [OverlayFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#modifying-files-or-directories) - seemed implied that file is deleted, but the image file is kept

  > When a file is deleted within a container, a whiteout file is created in the container (upperdir). The version of the file in the image layer (lowerdir) is not deleted
- [ZFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/#writing-files) - deleted:

  > If you create and then delete a file or directory within the container’s writable layer, the blocks are reclaimed by the zpool.
- [VFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/#how-the-vfs-storage-driver-works) is using a copy of the previous layer and work directly in a directory representing that layer, a deletion in the container should probably delete it from the related directory on host machine

> The documentation currently doesn't describe this special case.

Yes, and it probably won't ;)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! For the first part I've actually preached something similar. The second part of my question was about using `docker .. exec rm ..`, maybe I was not clear enough here. Any insights on that?

Comment: Edited my answer to add details

Comment: For AUFS, I'm really happy to read you came to the same conclusion! A small experiment, in which a file was deleted immediately after creation, at least confirmed this expectation.